# How do I get the 'Returning Player' exclusives?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I have a PS3 copy of GTA V and a PC copy of GTA V.  I've read about the bonuses you can get for being a returning player, such as a monster truck, a sub, stock car races, and a railgun.  **Can I unlock this content with what I have?**  If so, do I need to do anything special in the Rockstar Social Club to get this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an actual issue on PC, upon further investigation.  I think all the GTA 5 content is there, except for time-exclusive items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Source with additional information](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC):

What you need:

> 1. A copy of Grand Theft Auto V on PC.
> 2. Previous Grand Theft Auto Online character and progression data on PlayStation®3, PlayStation®4, Xbox 360 or Xbox One.
> 3. A Rockstar Games Social Club account. If you do not already have a Social Club account, you will need to create a new one as part of the
>      PC installation process. Click here for more info on creating an
>      account.
> 4. A PlayStation Network or Xbox Live account.

How to transfer:

> 1. Start Grand Theft Auto V on PC and log into the Social Club.
> 2. Enter GTA Online via the Character Select Wheel or the Pause Menu.
> 3. You will be given the option to transfer your previous GTA Online  character and progression data, along with the opportunity to change 
>      your character’s appearance again. If you wish to complete the 
>      transfer later, you can return to this option via the Online section 
>      of the Pause Menu.
> 4. Once you have chosen to transfer your previous character and progression data, the transferrable in-game money, RP and Rank of all
>      previous characters will be displayed. These are the characters that
>      will be transferred to PC. If you have previous character and
>      progression data on multiple systems, you will be prompted to select
>      one set of data. You can only transfer one set of character and
>      progression data for your Social Club account on PC.
> 5. Once the transfer has completed, you will be prompted to choose a character and enter GTA Online.

Comment: Follow up: Do you know if this just opens up the extra content for the migrated character or does it open up the content for all the GTA online characters (new or existing) associated with the Rockstar SC account?

Comment: @MadMAxJr No clue, it might be noted somewhere on that site.